# Is there any configuration option in Parsley.js that allows you to not add the parsley-success field to an input if you want to ignore it altogether?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I'm already excluding one input, and it adds the success class (which I don't mind)
`$('form').parsley({ excluded: '[data-parsley-sum-total="all"]' });`
but there are a number of other inputs that have no validations on them, and I don't want the `'parsley-success'` class added on submit.  If I add them to the list of excluded inputs, it still shows the `'parsley-success'` class after submission.  I'm just removing them manually right now on submit, but is there an option to not give them the class in the first place?

Using parsley 2.0.7
Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:
In case this helps, my inputs I'd like to have the validation show up on are all in a single div like so:

```
<form id="f">
  <input>
  <input>
  <div id="d">
      <input>
      <input>
  </div>
```

I'd like to do something like `$('#d').parsley()` but that obviously doesn't work.

Also, besides using parsley excluded like I mentioned above, using `data-parsley-group=""` doesn't work for me either, both just exclude from validations, but don't solve the parsley-success problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting point, it should be easier.

It's not too hard to get what you want though. You can listen for `parsley:field:validate` event, and toggle a class "no-constraint" depending on if it has constraints or not. A simple tweak to your CSS file will give the result you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow, do you mind elaborating on constraints?

Comment: Okay, so I figured out a solution more or less based on what you said, and just to clarify for future readers what I did:  I added a `no-constraint` class to the inputs that I wanted marked with the `parsley-success` and `parsley-error` classes and then changed the 6 lines of css in the parsley.css like so: `input.parsley-success.enrollment_input`